# Unable to patch "\caption" if the package caption is loaded

Tags: captions, etoolbox, patching

I was inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438122/add-chapter-name-in-the-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables) to make the chapter names appear in the list of figures.

This solution works very well if the `caption` package is not loaded. However, if this one (or `subcaption`) is loaded, I am unable to patch the `\caption` and `\pretocmd` from `etoolbox`doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to fix this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox, mwe}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thechaptername}{}
\newcounter{chapter@figure}
\newcounter{chapter@table}

\newif\ifinsideFigure
\newif\ifinsideTable

\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\insideFiguretrue}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\insideTabletrue}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}\renewcommand{\thechaptername}{#1}}

\pretocmd{\caption}{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{chapter}}{\value{chapter@figure}}%
        {}%
        {\ifinsideFigure%
            \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\numberline{\bfseries\thechapter\quad\thechaptername}}%
            \setcounter{chapter@figure}{\value{chapter}}%
        \fi}%
        {}{}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{chapter}}{\value{chapter@table}}%
        {}%
        {\ifinsideTable%
            \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\numberline{\bfseries\thechapter\quad\thechaptername}}%
            \setcounter{chapter@table}{\value{chapter}}%
            \fi}%
        {}{}%
}{}{\typeout{Fail}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter one}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{This is figure 1.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{This is figure 2.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter two}
\begin{table}
    A
    \caption{This is a table.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Chapter three}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{This is figure 3.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use `\pretocmd{\caption@caption}` which is the "permanent name" in the caption package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`caption` redefines `\caption` at `\begin{document}`, hence any patching to `\caption` before `\begin{document}` is overwritten. Using `\AtBeginDocument{\pretocmd...}` to delay the patch works.

Alternatively, you can use `\AddToHook{cmd/caption/before}{\ifnumequal ...}`, which requires latex2e 2021-06-01 or newer.